# Number of leaves in memsql cluster

Tags: singlestore

I have gone through https://help.memsql.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001091186-Odd-Number-of-Leaves-Configuration.

Is this recommendation applicable when we have leaf nodes in different availability regions or is this a general recommendation?

I have set up a memsql cluster with one master aggregator and 3 leaves.

But my hosts in `show leaves` command is not paired with any host. The Pair_Host column shows NULL.

Does this cause any problems to my cluster?

Answer (score 0):

Having an odd number of leaves only matters if you want to enable high availability (redundancy_level=2).  MemSQL currently only supports HA with availability groups that have the same number of leaves.